# Is there any way to make this flood fill faster in HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, performance, html, canvas, profiling

I'm using [this tutorial right now](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-canvas-javascript-paint-bucket-tool/) and I got it working perfectly, but my only concern is that it's a bit slow. I have a 600x600 canvas and when using the fill tool it will take about 2 seconds to fill the canvas. In Microsoft Paint to fill a canvas of the size is instant and to fill a canvas 10x that size (6000x6000) is still slightly shorter at around 1 second.

Is this just a limitation of javascript and the canvas element or could it be optimized to be near the speeds of desktop programs like MS Paint? I profiled it with Firebug and this function seems to be one of the main bottlenecks, but it does have to run every iteration so..

```
function matchStartColor(pixelPos, startR, startG, startB) {
    var r = colorLayerData.data[pixelPos];
    var g = colorLayerData.data[pixelPos + 1];
    var b = colorLayerData.data[pixelPos + 2];

    return (r == startR && g == startG && b == startB);
}
```

Comment: You might want to try a non-recursive flood-fill algorithm as apparently Chrome has stack limitations: http://www.somethinghitme.com/2012/03/07/html5-canvas-flood-fill/ . Also, maybe http://code.google.com/p/canvas-floodfill/ would be useful.

Comment: @AndrewMorton thanks for the mention, but my method is really susceptible to stack limitations (somethinghitme.com).

Comment: @Loktar I was using your web site article to point out that there could be limitations, but kudos for noticing your web site was mentioned :)

Comment: haha @AndrewMorton yeah I was actually attempting to answer this question when I saw the comment :P

Comment: @AndrewMorton: I just tried the google code one and it is much slower (2 or 3 times) than the one from the tutorial I linked in the original post. I notice some shockwave apps seem to have very fast and efficient flood fills. Is shockwave just faster than canvas and javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MS Paint is written in native code (C or C++ converted to machine code), which is far faster and, if correctly written, more efficient at rendering than canvas/javascript.  Consider also that MS Paint might use the video rendering facilities of the hardware on the computer, which I don't think canvas does by default in most browsers.

Also, MS Paint's flood/filling algorithm may be different than the one you're using.  There's always more than one way to achieve something.  Have you tried a simple line by line scan, filling in white pixels as you go?  You could try it, just for benchmarking purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I also followed this tutorial.This algorithm doesn't work for predefined images.It only works for things which you draw on canvas.

Comment: Because in real image some point you may think it is the same color but not(eg. rbg(100,100,100) vs rbg(99, 100, 99)) and of course in a photo, it will be more common.

Modify matchColor to return `(startR + toleranceR > r > startR - toleranceR) && so on`.
Hope this help.